# How can you rename columns in backpack for laravel datatable without renaming them from the model?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack

For instance, I want to rename id to Serial Number, how can I do this without changing in the model.
I want to create an alias column name that's easier on the eye.

[image]

Comment: you want to change the name `Id` to `Serial Number` on your front-end (blade), so its not related with model. Change it from blade

Answer (score 2):

every column (Model attribute for list and show operation) you want to show you can control the string that shown to the user (label) without changing the column name in DB:

for your case, just set the name to 'id', and the label to 'Serial Number', using text column, like in [doc](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/crud-columns#text):

```
 $this->crud->addColumn([
        'name'  => 'id',
        'label' => 'Serial Number',
        'type'  => 'text'
    ]);
```

you can use this code inside `setupShowOperation` and `setupListOperation`

Comment: Am i doing this in the CrudController for my entity?

Comment: yes, inside setupShowOperation and setupListOperation

Comment: To build upon OMR's excellent answer - alternatively, if you've added your column using the fluent syntax, just add `->label('Serial Number')` to the end of your column definition chain. It does the exact same thing, the array syntax and the fluent syntax.